# How do I modify the system PATH in Windows 2003/Windows 2008 using a script?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, environment-variables

How do I modify the system PATH environment variable using script (or even a registry setting) so that when Windows boots it's already configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My google-fu was lacking earlier. The way to do this is using the SETX tool:

```
SETX NEWVAR %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv /M
SETX PATH %PATH%;%NEWVAR% /M
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find environment variables at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment.

Comment: Thanks...all I needed for now was to be able to set them in a batch file. But bookmarked for future ref.